# Setting `scroll-margin` for `term-mode` using `unless` is not working

Tags: term, conditionals

I want to set default value of `scroll-margin` to 3 but for `ansi-term` I want it to be 0. To do this I have added a hook to `term-mode-hook` which worked fine.

```lisp
(setq scroll-margin 3)                          
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook                       
          (lambda ()                                 
            (make-local-variable 'scroll-margin)
            (setq scroll-margin 0)))
```

But earlier I used `unless` to do the same thing which didn't work and I don't understand why. Could someone please help why below snippet didn't work to do the same task?

```lisp
(unless (derived-mode-p 'term-mode)
  (setq scroll-margin 3))
```

Comment: Did you execute that code by hand? In your init file? In a hook? What was the mode of the buffer that was current when you executed it?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @NickD I entered this code in my `init.el` file, saved it and opened a new `emacs` instant. With the first snippet, I could see positive results whereas after second snippet, I didn't see what I expected.

Comment: Right - your `init.el` gets executed in the context of a buffer (probably `*scratch*`) whose major mode (probably `lisp-interaction-mode`) is not a derived mode of `term-mode`, so the conditional evaluates to nil and scroll-margin is left at its default value (probably 0).

Comment: I expected it to work like: unless current mode is not `term-mode`, set `scroll-margin` to 3 and when major mode is `term-mode`, keep it to default which is 0. Where am I going wrong in understanding?

Comment: Let me know if the answer explains things clearly enough.

Comment: Thanks, your answer made it clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the second bit of code into your init.el:

```
(unless (derived-mode-p 'term-mode)
  (setq scroll-margin 3))
```

and that code gets executed, it asks: "Is the mode of the current buffer a derived mode of `term-mode`?" - the answer is "No", since the current buffer is `*scratch*`, the major mode is `lisp-interaction-mode` and that is *not* a derived mode of `term-mode`. You can do that experiment yourself: create a file `foo.el` in the current directory and add this to is:

```
(message (symbol-name major-mode))
(message (buffer-name))

(message (if (derived-mode-p 'term-mode) "True" "False"))

(unless (derived-mode-p 'term-mode)
  (setq scroll-margin 3))
```

Now start up emacs with this file as your init file:

```
emacs -Q -l foo.el`
```

and check the `*Messages*` buffer - you should see something like this:

```
lisp-interaction-mode
*scratch*
False
```

As you can see, the conditional evaluates to nil, so the setting of `scroll-margin` is skipped.[1]

To summarize: when the contents of init.el are evaluated, that is done in a buffer that is unrelated to any `term-mode` buffer you later create, so it cannot possibly have an effect.

The first code fragment:

```
(setq scroll-margin 3)                          
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook                       
          (lambda ()                                 
            (make-local-variable 'scroll-margin)
            (setq scroll-margin 0)))
```

says: unconditionally set `scroll-margin` to 3. Then, when you create a new buffer and set its major mode to `term-mode` (or a derived mode of it), the `term-mode-hook` is run: that calls all of the functions in the hook and in particular the function you added, which sets `scroll-margin` to 0 locally in that buffer.

The effect is that `scroll-margin` is 3 in all buffers, except for `term-mode` buffers (and buffers whose mode is a derived mode of `term-mode`) where `scroll-margin` is set to 0 for those buffers only.

[1] The details might vary, depending on how exactly you start. E.g. if I copy the above `foo.el` to `$HOME/.emacs` and start up emacs without any options, I get `fundamental-mode` instead of `lisp-interaction-mode`but there is no other significant difference.